# Разница между использованием примитивов и объектными типами в java

Tags: java, объекты, примитивы

В случае если нужно объявить переменную числового типа в java, то какой тип  нужно использовать скалярный int или объектный Integer. Чем нужно руководствоваться при выборе?

Comment: Если нужно класть в коллекции, то `Integer`. Во всех остальных случаях по возможности лучше использовать примитивы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer` приходится использовать, когда нужно класть в коллекции данные:

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

У `Integer` происходит боксинг/анбоксинг. К тому же, оно использует больше памяти.

Если подвести итог:

> По возможности лучше всегда использовать примитивы (`int` и т.п).